# Systemd - detect in ExecStopPost whether service exited without error

Tags: linux, systemd

I have an application that after it's finished and exited normally should not be restarted. After this app has done its business I'd like to shutdown the instance (ec2). I was thinking of doing this using systemd unit files with the options

```
Restart=on-failure
ExecStopPost=/path/to/script.sh
```

The script that should run on `ExecStopPost`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# sleep 1; adding sleep didn't help

# this always comes out deactivating
service_status=$(systemctl is-failed app-importer) 

# could also do the other way round and check for failed
if [ $service_status = "inactive" ] 
then
  echo "Service exited normally: $service_status . Shutting down..."
  #shutdown -t 5
else
  echo "Service did not exit normally - $service_status"
fi
exit 0
```

The problem is that when post stop runs I can't seem to detect whether the service ended normally or not, the status then is `deactivating`, only after do I know if it enters a `failed` state or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that systemd considers the service to be `deactivating` until the `ExecPostStop` process finishes.  Putting sleeps in doesn't help since it's just going to wait longer.  The idea for an `ExecPostStop` was to clean up anything the service might leave behind, like temp files, UNIX sockets, etc.  The service is not done, and ready to start again, until the cleanup is finished.  So what systemd is doing does make sense if you look at it that way.

What you should do is check `$SERVICE_RESULT`, `$EXIT_CODE` and/or `$EXIT_STATUS` in your script, which will tell you how the service stopped.  Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo running exec post script | logger
systemctl is-failed foobar.service | logger
echo $SERVICE_RESULT, $EXIT_CODE and $EXIT_STATUS | logger
```

When service is allowed to to run to completion:

```
Sep 17 05:58:14  systemd[1]: Started foobar.
Sep 17 05:58:17  root[1663]: foobar service will now exit
Sep 17 05:58:17  root[1669]: running exec post script
Sep 17 05:58:17  root[1671]: deactivating
Sep 17 05:58:17  root[1673]: success, exited and 0
```

And when the service is stopped before it finishes:

```
Sep 17 05:57:22  systemd[1]: Started foobar.
Sep 17 05:57:24  systemd[1]: Stopping foobar...
Sep 17 05:57:24  root[1643]: running exec post script
Sep 17 05:57:24  root[1645]: deactivating
Sep 17 05:57:24  root[1647]: success, killed and TERM
Sep 17 05:57:24  systemd[1]: Stopped foobar.
```

Comment: `systemctl stop foobar.service and kill $(pidof foobar_app)` both yield success, killed and TERM on ExecStopPost and the foobar moves into "inactive" or dead state. Is there a way to differentiate between the foobar moving into "failed" state vs foobar moving into "inactive" state ? `$SERVICE_RESULT, $EXIT_CODE and/or $EXIT_STATUS` aren't helping here.

Comment: So you want to do something if the service completes normally, or is force stopped by systemd, but not if it fails for a reason other than being stopped by systemd?

Comment: I want to handle service failures in particular (core-dumps, EXIT_FAILURE, non-maskable signals, etc) while user initiated SIGTERMs should be allowed. Particularly, I want to know if the service would restart or not in ExecStopPost. $SERVICE_RESULT is advertised to hold "start-limit-burst" but it never shows that value even after configuring the limit burst intervals and the service hitting the burst-limits

Comment: In your case, you might try adding `SuccessAction=reboot` to the `Unit` section.  This will trigger if the service finishes and returns 0, is stopped via systemctl, is killed via TERM.  It will not trigger if the service is killed via SEGV or returns a non-zero code.